# Swift how to animate fixed uiview from right to left

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make my view animate from right to left & change colour unlike the example from dribbble. Currently, my view is moving around the screen not staying fixed to the original position. I'm trying to make it look like this example here but can't seem to make it animate from right to left properly. https://dribbble.com/shots/5690048-Social-Meet-Up-UI-Kit

```
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.autoreverse.rawValue | UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat.rawValue | UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: options), animations: {

        // any changes entered in this block will be animated
        self.goingBackgrondView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.goingBackgrondView.frame = CGRect(x: 320-50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 55)

    }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not move animation. That is resize animation.

Change this:

```
self.goingBackgrondView.frame = CGRect(x: 320-50, y: 0, width: 50, height: 55)
```

to this:

```
self.goingBackgrondView.frame = CGRect(x: 320, y: 0, width: 0, height: 55)
```

Comment: Did you see the answer? Does it help?